# OSx Yosemite - turn on memory compression

Tags: macos, memory

So I noticed after manual restart( for some reason mac was freezing ) that my mac has become very slow. I checked at Activity monitor and saw that there was no memory compression at all and the pagefile was about 1.6 gb( before page file was couple of megabytes ).

Checking at the terminal:

```
sysctl vm.compressor_mode -> returns vm.compressor_mode: 4
sudo nvram boot-args  -> Error getting variable boot-args: data was not found
```

Do you  have any ideas how can i return my memory compression. Restart won't fix it.